# Create a dictionary using a for loop and a function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, dictionary, for-loop

I have an array with postal codes and I want to build a dictionary with the postal codes and the result of a function related to them. (Basically the loop goes to a DataFrame and looks how many different 'CouncilArea' are there for each postal code).

This is the for loop i've tried:

```
for cps in codigos_postales:
codigo_postal_council = {}  
codigo_postal_council[cps] = pd.notna(pd.unique(data[data['Postcode']==cps]['CouncilArea'])).sum()
```

The problem is that in the output I don't get the full dictionary with postal codes and results. I only get the last item of the array and the result of the function as output.

```
{3793.0: 0}
```

I know the function I coded is working properly because if i include this code in the loop I get a long print of results.

```
print(pd.notna(pd.unique(data[data['Postcode']==cps]['CouncilArea'])).sum())
```

I've searched the web for about and hour and still not getting a solution.
Thank you very much for your kind support!!!

Comment: `for cps in codigos_postales: data[data['Postcode']==cps]['CouncilArea']` would be much faster with some sort of `groupby`.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More the dict creation outside loop

```
codigo_postal_council = {} 
for cps in codigos_postales:
    codigo_postal_council[cps] = pd.notna(pd.unique(data[data['Postcode']==cps]['CouncilArea'])).sum()
```

Comment: That's it, it's working correctly now!! Thank you very much for your reply :)